# In react-native project Importing drawer cause an error

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, drawer

I am a beginner react-native developer and still learning things from different sources, currently I started creating small project where I decided to use drawer navigation. I followed the source and created the project as it was written but after importing drawer component (which consists to routes) in App.tsx, It cause an error "Cannot read property "is Configured" of undefined" please help me solve this problem . The code is small and please check it:

https://github.com/sabaPhruidze/ReviewApplication

I tried this source for solving the case but it did not solve it "https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/"

Comment: Please anyone help me on this project

Comment: Hi, @SabaPhruidze, please edit your question to include your code formatted as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  For questions about debugging code on StackOverflow, it is required that the code be included in the question itself and not only as a link to an external source.